# Dismissing custom alert view and unwind segue issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a very specific problem which I can not manage. I have an application which uses `Storyboard` and `custom segues`.

I have a view controller in which I have to show custom alert view to confirm or deny action on button press. The custom alert is build as view with title text and 2 buttons for **Confirm** and **Cancel**.

On initial init I add observer for that custom alert view:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(customAlertViewNotoficationHandler:)
                                                 name: constDismissCustomAlertViewNotificationLabel object:nil];
```

On button press I create view and show it using:

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I press **Cancel** I just dismiss view. The method is implemented inside custom class:

```
-(void) doDismissAlert:(NSString*) isConfirm {

    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    //raise notification about dismiss
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:constDismissCustomAlertViewNotificationLabel
     object:isConfirm];

}
```

`isConfirm` shows if I press **Confirm** or **Cancel** button.

If I confirm action I have to call SOAP service. It starts in a separate thread and returns result of confirmation (for SOAP service I use [sudzc.com](http://sudzc.com)). If there are no errors I continue to another view controller using custom segue: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segRec2RecDet" sender: self];`

Segue perform looks:

```
- (void)perform {
    [[self sourceViewController] presentViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If I have **Session expired** error I have to go to the **Login** view controller. For this action I use `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwSegReturnToLogin" sender:self];` to go to **Login**. This is where my problem appears. I receive error:

```
2014-12-09 11:43:27.558 PA-PAY[10605:613] attempt to dismiss modal view controller
whose view does not currently appear. self = <PESvcRecharge: 0x7f9920e7d030>
modalViewController = <PESavCustomAlertView: 0x7f9920f82990>
2014-12-09 11:43:27.558 PA-PAY[10605:613] attempt to dismiss modal view controller
whose view does not currently appear. self = <PESvcLogin: 0x7f9920d37f00>
modalViewController = <PESvcRecharge: 0x7f9920e7d030>
```

Obviously there is attempt to dismiss PESavCustomAlertView which is already in process of dismiss and the it can not go to PESvcLogin.

It is very strange that in simulator when I use iOS 8.1 the above code works. It crashes in 7.1

Any suggestions how to deal with that?

**EDIT**

My hierarchy of view looks like (only for this section of the logic):

**Login VC** -> **Menu VC** -> **Recharge VC** -> **(Custom Alert)** -> **Ticket VC**

**Custom alert** is required only because my specification requires that it must look like that. I also can have normal alert view to show that there is an error. If the error is **Session expired** I have to go back to **Login VC**.

Remark: **Custom Alert** is not part of **Story board**. It is xib file connected with my custom class.

Comment: It looks like you have a stack of 2 modal view controllers, and it's trying to dismiss them at the same time, but I don't really have a clear picture of your view hierarchy. If it's crashing in 7 but not in 8, I would first wonder if it's a UIKit race condition. Have you tried turning off animations? Could you post some more info of the view stack?

Comment: Yes, @P-double I have 2 modal VC which I want to dismiss. I am not sure that it is "at the same time". In the notification of dismiss method I try to make unwind. I suppose that the problem is that **Custom Alert** is not dismissed. Also **Custom Alert** is not part of **Story board**.

Comment: Actually I fix it by setting dismiss animation to `NO`. 10x for suggestion.

Comment: So it looks like a race condition, there was some issues with view hierarchy corruption in iOS 7 when animating between view controllers

Comment: One remark - I set dismiss animation to NO for iOS > 8 for **Custom Alert**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning animations off could fix the issue, although I suspect deeper problems with your view stack management code. Code that should run after the modal view controller is dismissed should be added to the completion block of

`[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Allowing you to retain the animation behaviour

ie

```
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        // Post notfication here

    }];
```

Comment: I am not sure what type of post notification I must have. For that reason, @P-double, I will leave it this way.